# Why does the energy of an electron depend on the size of the well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, schroedinger-equation

In the square well the energy states of the electron depend on the width of the square well. That means that by changing the physical shape of the confinement region (making it a parabolic well) or making the width twice as big, or twice as small, would affect the observable energy states of the electron.

Maybe I just forgot, or maybe I never-stood why this should be the case? I don't think there's a classical analog to this QM affect? If I stick a soccer ball in my book bag vs in my garage vs in my house. The ball doesn't get more or less energy depending on where I confine it. Yet, the electron seemingly gets more kinetic energy. At least in a infinite square well, with zero potential. If I make the width smaller the energy goes up. So why not do this forever, and make the electron have infinite energy? Sorry that's a question in a question.

Comment: Notice that in case with quantum mechanics we work with probabilities and not certainties. Also, the ball in the garage doesn’t move, whereas an electron does. And it can have different energies in the different parts of the well, with different probabilities.

Comment: Why is the pitch of a flute higher than that of a bassoon?

Comment: Thanks @nicael. That's a great point, I definitely am thinking about a ball at rest in a garage. And you're right even the ground state electron has some energy, which is all KE since V=0. SO the question then becomes why/how can I change the ground state of this object just by squeezing in the walls. That's weird.

Comment: Imaging yourself standing in a well with walls as high as 20cm. There’s a large probability that you can get outside the well, since walls are really low. Now imagine the walls now are 200cm. With this height of walls, if you’re somewhat athletic, you can still climb out of the well, but the probability this time is lower. Now let’s make walls as high as 20 m. With this height you can’t climb out at all, but suddenly someone drops you a mountain-climbing inventory and you still climb out. See how changing the wall height changes the probability of escaping?

Comment: The point is, you have confused the probabilities with certainties. In case with quantum mechanics, we work with probabilities and once the well is changed, then the probability of you being at any points of the well and outside if it - does also change. In the case above, we managed to change the probability of you being outside of the well by increasing wall height.

Comment: @nicael. Not to be that person, as it probably wasn't clear from the "basic" nature of my question, but I've got two degrees in physics.  That being said, you're point about the probabilistic nature of QM is well taken.  I don't think that's what's causing my confusion here though. The lowering of the walls and having more energetic particles escape works just fine knowing using thermo, we don't really even need QM for that. The issue of the energy being effected by width, feels different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have pointed out the basics:

- The energy of a particle depends on its frequency $E=\hbar\omega$.
- Stationary bound states of an infinite square well form standing waves based on the width of the well.
- The width of the well sets the longest wavelength $\rightarrow$ lowest frequency $\rightarrow$ lowest energy available to the particle.

So why can't you squeeze the box and get infinite energy by raising the ground state?  The energy gained by the electron has to come from somewhere.
In fact it takes energy to change the size of the box.  Imagine the infinite square well has one moveable wall.  The work you do to move the wall will be transferred to the electron wave in the box.  You can figure out how much work you need to do, just from thinking about how the electron's energy changes.

This is analogous to the work you do on a box of gas in thermodynamics.  When you squeeze a box of gas, it takes work to overcome the pressure and maybe raise the internal energy of the gas.

Assuming the electron stays in the $n=1$ ground state the whole time while you squeeze the box:
$$W = \Delta E = E_f - E_i = \frac{\pi^2\hbar^2}{2 m_e}\left[\frac{1}{L_f^2}-\frac{1}{L_i^2} \right].$$
Taking the limit that $L_f\rightarrow 0$, we see it would take infinite work to compress the box all the way to zero.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Yes, so you can't get the infinity, b/c you need to put it work. Perfect and the ideal gas analog makes perfect sense. BUT in an ideal gas, as you squeeze the walls of the container, you reduce the volume and therefore end up increasing the pressure (I think you can do it while keeping T=const). But this is just one electron? Or if you do it with Q=0, the work you do is really getting transferred to KE of the gas b/c they are hitting the wall sooner? You are giving them more $p$. So what is the energy transference mechanism here?

Comment: The energy of the electron is $E = V + K$. Inside the well $V=0$, so the work done directly adds to the electron's kinetic energy.  I don't think it is helpful to treat the electron as a particle bouncing around the box in this case.  It is behaving like a wave.  Changing the size of the box, causes the frequency of the standing electron wave to change.

Comment: Yeah, I think switching to thinking about it like a wave makes sense. Other answers have alluded to that as well. Using the wave solution from solving the boundary value of the Schrodinger eq. So then another question, if we start squeezing the walls we're doing work, but you need to do more and more work b/c the energy will go up as $L$ goes down. Why is that? It's still just one electron? What's creating this "pressure" that's making us work harder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fulfill the boundary conditions, which are $\psi(0)=0$ and $\psi(L)=0$ with $L$ being the width of the well with infinite high walls.
Consider the one-dimensional and stationary Schrödinger equation for vanishing potential:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x)
=E\psi(x)
\end{equation}
(The stationary Schrödinger equation for vanishing potential is a Helmholtz equation mathmatically. Since the Laplace operator only has negative eigenvalues and $m>0$, we have $E>0$.) A solution is of the form $\psi(x)=A\sin(ax)+B\cos(bx)$. The boundary condition $\psi(0)=0$ immediatly yields $B=0$, so $\psi(x)=A\sin(ax)$. Putting this into the upper equation yields:
\begin{equation}
E=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}a^2
\end{equation}
Since we have the boundary condition $\psi(L)=0$ left, $a$ can't be arbitrary. ($A$ can't be as well, since $\psi$ has to be normed with $\|\psi\|_{L^2}=1$.) We get:
\begin{equation}
\psi(L)=A\sin(aL)\stackrel{!}{=}0
\Rightarrow\mathop{\exists}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\colon
aL=n\pi
\Rightarrow
E=\frac{\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}n^2
\end{equation}
The energy is therefore dependend on the width $L$ and also the new *quantum number* $n$ giving rise to the *quantization of energy*. I also remembered a nice little cartoon explaing this, but couldn't find it again, so I just drew it myself:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes. That all looks correct, but I don't know that it gets at my question. So the dependence on L pops out of the boundary equation. But that implies I can make $L$ smaller and give the electron more energy. Why does my act of confinement change the energy of the thing I'm trying to confine?

Comment: It does get perfectly at your question. The energy basically describes how fast the wave oscillates and when it has to vanish at both sides of the well, you can not have every oscillation possible. Decreasing the size of the well squeezes the wave, therefore increases the number of oscillations and hence the energy. Your implication is correct. Quantum mechanics is a bizarre world, it's not easy to imagine or accept that changing some things that seem to have nothing to do with other things, does indeed change them too. A good example is the Aharonov-Bohm effect. That is finest black magic.

Answer (score 1):

The quintessence of non-relativistic quantum mechanics is that microscopic objects do not behave as classical particles, where for the latter we do not expect quantised energy levels if they are confined within a certain region. (Such a confined region is what the 'infinite well' simulates, although in the end it is of course unrealistic, since there are no infinite potentials). I am sure you saw the math: The Schroedinger equation asks for a wave like solution to the problem, and a wave that is zero at the boundaries can only have discrete number of crests and nodes, corresponding to the allowed energy levels of the electron.

If the electron would be in a well that is much much wider than the typical wavelength corresponding to the electron, the energy levels would also get closer and closer. Remember that the energy levels scale with the square of the inverse of the well's width, meaning that also the lowest energy level tends to zero if the well is wide.

If you want to compare this with the macroscopic ball, but want to see it as a quantum object, you have to realise that it's corresponding deBroglie wavelength will be minuscule due to it's large mass. So putting it in a garage corresponds to incredible close energy levels that seem continuous, since such a container is much larger than the corresponding deBroglie wavelength. I would also think you are thinking about a ball with basically zero kinetic energy. Even classically the situation could be different if it moves and decreasing the containers size would increase the balls kinetic energy (see below).

If you have an electron within a well at lowest energy level, then it's energy should increase when you make the well smaller, while I would imagine the energy comes from the energy from the 'moving' potential well. I think heuristically this can be pictured analogous to a moving classical point particle within two walls. The energy would be constant if all the collisions are elastic, but it would gain energy from collisions with the wall if that would move towards it, making the confined region smaller. However, I don't think this analogy holds pretty well.

Comment: Totally get the un-realism of the infinite square well. I'm definitely using it to try and keep things simple, but I imagine in general there is this confinement thing, which I think you're getting at with the walls and elastics collisions point. The issue I'm having is, the electron isn't necessarily bouncing off the walls?

Answer (score 1):

A particle in a box with "hard" walls is described by a wavefunction that is a standing wave which vanishes at the walls.  The electron energy is proportional to the wave frequency, $E=\hbar \omega.$  If one compares the ground state energies of two electrons in boxes of different sizes, the electron in the smaller box will have a smaller wavelength, which means a higher frequency, which means a higher ground state energy than the electron in the larger box. This qualitative argument explains the $L$ in the denominator of $E=\dfrac{n^2 \pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}.$

The same argument can be applied to wells with finite walls.  For wells of the same depth, the width essentially determines the size of the wavelength of the bound states.

Answer (score 0):

A confined particle will have some nonzero kinetic energy due to the uncertainty principle,

$$
\sigma_p \sigma_x \ge \hbar/2
$$

because the way to compute the uncertainty is

$$
\sigma_p^2 = \left<p^2\right> - \left<p\right>^2
$$

The stationary states of the square well are … well, they’re stationary, with $\left<p\right> = 0$, achieved as the sum of a left-going and right-going wave.  But the whole point of the Schrödinger equation is to find wavefunctions $\psi$ for which
$
\left(
\frac{\hat p^2}{2m} - \hat E
\right)
\psi = 0
$.
The zero-energy solution is $\psi=0$, which we reject because it can’t be normalized.

Note that if someone twisted your arm and forced you to accept $\psi(x) = \text{constant}$ as a wavefunction, it would have zero energy, but also $\left<x^2\right>=\infty$, so the uncertainty principle is still followed.

A useful homework problem is to compute $\sigma_p$ and $\sigma_x$ for the states of the square well, or of the harmonic oscillator, or whichever other potential interests you.  In general the ground state is closest to a minimum-uncertainty wave packet.

A sports ball which is rolling around your garage is a “classical object” because its de Broglie wavelength $\lambda = h/p$ is smaller than its actual size.  Even if your sports ball is at rest, thermal motions mean it remains a classical object.  Another useful homework problem is to compare the quantum-mechanical confinement energy of a golf ball in a bag to its thermal energy. You can also compare the confinement energy associated with squeezing the golf ball into some smaller volume with the work it would take to squeeze a golf ball in a vise.